# AndEngine Sound.play() decreases body's velocity

Tags: android, box2d, andengine, audio

I am developing a platform game using AndEngine. Character keeps running and collect coins. I am playing sound when character collides with some coin. It works fine when coins are in horizontal sequence and are at some distance relative to each other. But when character collides with bunch of coins, character jerks and game slow downs the body's velocity. Character's speed suddenly comes close to zero.[image]

Character's sprite is connected to a physics body and I am settings its speed using `body.setLinearVelocity()` method. Here is how I am detecting collision of sprite and coins and playing sound.

```
protected void checkCoinCollisions() {
    for(int i = mCoins.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        Coin coin = mCoins.get(i);
        if(hero.collidesWith(coin)) {
            mCoinsCollected++;
            mScene.detachChild(coin);

            coinSound.play();

            mCoins.remove(coin);
        }

    }
}
```

Any idea how to remove this slowdown of character and jerk?

Comment: So you're saying that if you compare the value returned by GetLinearVelocity before and after calling that function, it's different?

Comment: no actually, before colliding with coins, it runs smoothly, but after collision, it slow downs suddenly.

Comment: You already mentioned that. I'm talking about the value returned by GetLinearVelocity... does it change after you call checkCoinCollisions?